# Problems connecting to mysql database in xampp

Tags: php

I have this code that is supposed to connect my website to a database that i created in xampp.

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'anyons');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');


$field1_name=$_POST['email'];
$field2_name=$_POST['pass'];
$field3_name=$_POST['name'];
$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)or die("Failed to connect to 
MySQL: " . mysql_error());
@mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO login VALUES('$field1_name','$field2_name',
'$field3_name')";mysql_query($query);mysql_close();
?>
```

I get an error Unable to select database, meaning there's a broken connection somewhere. i have been trying to figure it out but i really can't. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Thomas this is a matter of opinion and up to OP what they want to use.  Although mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: @NigelRen you missed the point. PDO is not only connected with OOP, but also is more flexible, and enables connecting with many other DBs. Abstraction provided by PDO is more convinient to use

Comment: What's more mysql_* is removed, not deprecated

Comment: you can't connected to database as there is `@` in your `mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME,$con)` and use mysqli_* function instead of mysql_* funtion

Answer (score 0):

You have combined the connection used by `mysqli` and `mysql`

replace your codes by following codes

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'anyons');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
// connection checking
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// filtering values
extract($_POST); // collected all post values
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $pass);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);

$query = "INSERT INTO login (email, pass, name) VALUES ('{$email}','{$pass}','{$name}')";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}else{
    echo 'records added!';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```